# How to pay in INR through Braintree Payment Gateway

Tags: android, android-studio, paypal, payment-gateway, braintree

I am trying to Pay through Android Application. I am using Braintree payment gateway. By default, it is paying in EURO. How can I change from EURO to INR?

Comment: Your question is little confusing, as could not figure out whether you are a user or a developer. If developer then while setting up merchant account inside your braintree account you can set currency. If user then you cannot change if that option is not provided by application owner.

Comment: are you using payment though token ? please post your code too.

Comment: I logged in Braintree by Login through Paypal and I am a developer.

Comment: Yes I a using Payment through Token